# How can you redefine a property using in reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, properties

Let's assume we have the following class:

```
public class tx_fct
{

    int _ok;

    public int ok 
    {
        get
        {
            return _ok;
        }
        set
        {
            _ok = value;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I override the getter using reflection?

The getter doesn't seem to be in `tx_fct1.ok.GetType().GetMethods()`.

When I do get access to the getter, how do I insert my own getter code?

Comment: I'd want to know more about the design of what you're trying to accomplish -- it sounds a lot like you want to override the existing behavior of a class, and there are mechanisms in place (assuming you have source-level access to tx_fct) to make such possible without jumping through the reflection hoop.

Comment: I have access to tx_fct, but I cannot modify it, this really has to be done at runtime, so I cant inherit and use new. It seems only reflexion can let me do this at runtime...

Comment: Looks like you're checking the methods on the ok itself, which is an int.  Get the type of the class (tx_fct) and get methods on there and you will see get_ and set_ for ok.

Comment: @Enriquev: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? (I mean, for what purpose?) This sounds a lot like code injection, and there simply HAS to be a better way ...

Comment: Yay! you are right, I found it in tx_fct1.GetType().GetMethods(), its called get_ok, If I do tx_fct1.GetType().GetMethod("get_ok"), it works, but now how do I redefine it? Say instead of it doing "return _ok;", I want it to do "return (3 * _ok)" ?

Comment: @John Yes you are right this is code injection on an instance of an existing predifined class (that is generated at runtime not by me), all this for code compatibility, so I can make the class do what I want it to do, I dont really need to multiply this int by 3, what I want to do is way more but I simplified the usage so explanations dont overshadow my goal

Comment: Have you considered just creating a wrapper class that encapsulates an instance of tx_fct and exposes your customized behavior via its own means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection API provides only methods to create classes and methods, but not modify existing ones.
It is not possible to modify existing method in runtime. All you can do is to inject some IL into assembly which has not yet been loaded into the AppDomain.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly, you would need inheritance:

```
public class tx_fct {
    int _ok;
    public virtual int ok {
        get { return _ok; }
        set { _ok = value; }
    }
}
class custom_fct : tx_fct {
    public override int ok {
        get {
            Console.WriteLine("get");
            return base.ok;
        }
        set {
            Console.WriteLine("set");
            base.ok = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can create subclasses at runtime using `AssemblyBuilder`, `TypeBuilder`, etc - but it isn't fun, and should be reserved for when you absolutely need it.